# Address of (&) gives compiler generated address or loader generated address?

Tags: c, compiler-construction, virtual, loader, memory-address

```
int a;
printf("address is %u", &a);
```

Which address is this..? I mean is this a compiler generated address i.e. virtual address or the loader given physical address in the RAM..?

As it prints different address every time, I guess it must be address in the RAM. Just want to make sure.

Please provide any links which give reference to your answer.

Comment: most most most likely virtual.  unless you program a system with real address space, eg arduino

Comment: If this is for a Windows 7 PC or similar computer, then yes, it will be a virtual address. But on some systems it will be the physical memory address. Since you don't tell us what system you are using, it is impossible to answer the question.

Comment: This is a virtual address if there's virtual to physical address translation present. If not, physical (unless your program runs in an interpreter or in a VM, in which case it can be something else). This address is based on the location that the loader chooses for your application. For various reasons this address may vary (e.g. security reasons or simply the last location being already occupied by something else).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct answer is: "it depends."

(The printf should use the "%p" directive, and cast the address to "void *", for the sake of well-defined-ness:

```
printf("%p\n", (void *)&a);
```

although using %u no doubt works for your particular compiler with whatever flags you are using.)

As @Alex noted, the address is virtual if translation is going on (as with most modern OSes, or even when running in "emulated physical" under a virtual machine).  The address itself is generally determined at link or load time if "a" has static storage duration, but at runtime (on the stack as @Als said) if not.  Variables declared "static" or "extern" have static duration; variables declared outside function bodies have static duration; and variables declared within function bodies, but without using either "extern" or "static", have automatic storage duration (and are thus usually on "the stack"—though there can be more than one stack, as when using POSIX threads).

Answer (score 4):

The address returned for a local variable in the user space is always a virtual address not the physical address.

The variable `a` in your case is allocated on the local storage(stack) and every time you execute your program a stack space allocated to your function, the variable is located at particular offset within this stack frame, since the address of the stack being allocated to your program can be different everytime the address returned for the variable will be different as well.

Comment: *Always a virtual address* What if the code is running on a CPU running in real mode? Assuming the CPU is x86, even.

Comment: Then why is it different every time..? If compiled only once, it should return same address every time I run the code.

Comment: No no no... the compiler generated address is virtual address and it is returned by '&' operator. So where does the local stack come into the picture..? And if local stack address is returned it is physical, right..?

Comment: @Adorn: If in the OS there's one address space for all processes and memory can be allocated and freed before your program starts, your program may be unable to be loaded at the same address every time. Also, the OS may be using [Address Space Randomization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization) to thwart consistent exploitation of security defects in your program. It achieves that by loading the program at different addresses so the exploits cannot rely on a fixed location.

Answer (score 3):

On any modern OS **all** addresses that you ever see on a C level are virtual addresses. The example that you give is a variable on the stack, and the reason why this'd be different on every execution is that the (virtual) stack address is randomized for security reasons.

But in any case, even global symbols that are resolved by the loader have virtual addresses in the address space of the process.

(All of this might not be true for embedded devices but this is usually nothing that you will encounter when learning C)

Answer (score 0):

> I mean is this a compiler generated address i.e. virtual address or
>   the loader given physical address in the RAM.

False dichotomy. The address generated by the compiler is relocated by the linker, and it is this address that is returned by &. It is a virtual address unless you are running on something odd like NetWare 3 that doesn't use VM.